# Octave buffering console output

Tags: octave

I'm new to Octave.

I'm working with a huge matrix with thousands of rows and just 2 columns.

When I print it the terminal seems to be cutting part of it, but I want the whole thing to be shown.

Any way to do that or maybe to redirect the output in a file or something?

I had the same in problem in Eclipse but it was much easier to solve the same issue back then.

Comment: Pagination is on by default in Octave. `more` will toggle the value between on/off, `more off` will turn it off. See https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Paging-Screen-Output.html

Comment: where should I find this more? can't find it in the settings

Comment: I gave you a link to the documentation. It's a command that you type in on the command line. You can probably also put it in your .octaverc file. That may not be what you're looking for, so you might look at `page_screen_output(0)` like [this](https://wiki.octave.org/.octaverc).

Comment: ok thank you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to redirect a Matrix to a file use save

```
A=rand(5,5)
A =

   0.552789   0.570720   0.896715   0.982821   0.622758
   0.704791   0.514302   0.380680   0.344768   0.459588
   0.230478   0.744468   0.668264   0.659316   0.414710
   0.819015   0.572315   0.404128   0.074092   0.813156
   0.099461   0.031186   0.499781   0.758091   0.243281

 save("-ascii","file-ascii.txt","A")
 save("file-text.txt","A")
```

pure text

```
$ cat  file-ascii.txt
 5.52789005e-01 5.70719716e-01 8.96714571e-01 9.82821412e-01 6.22757836e-01
 7.04791031e-01 5.14301972e-01 3.80679512e-01 3.44768074e-01 4.59587827e-01
 2.30478499e-01 7.44467506e-01 6.68264066e-01 6.59315817e-01 4.14709954e-01
 8.19014881e-01 5.72314594e-01 4.04128230e-01 7.40916214e-02 8.13155903e-01
 9.94607828e-02 3.11857103e-02 4.99780576e-01 7.58091470e-01 2.43280663e-01
```

octave default style

```
 $ cat  file-text.txt
# Created by Octave 5.2.0, Wed May 27 21:43:22 2020 CEST <Marco@LAPTOP-82F08ILC>
# name: A
# type: matrix
# rows: 5
# columns: 5
 0.55278900467056769 0.57071971558810353 0.89671457115004172 0.98282141203898321 0.622757835845834
 0.70479103140202992 0.51430197227101204 0.3806795123567624 0.34476807355856237 0.45958782700965189
 0.2304784985452572 0.74446750644064241 0.66826406647042169 0.65931581744685042 0.41470995365627888
 0.81901488130574696 0.57231459443213173 0.40412823039438278 0.074091621362711677 0.81315590327055964
 0.099460782832668723 0.031185710267227097 0.49978057628118927 0.75809147040922908 0.24328066285306477
```